# Дополнительные параметры setTimeout

Tags: javascript

Объясните, какие дополнительные параметры передаются в функцию setTimeout, помимо времени и функции, которая будет выполняться? Желательно с небольшим примером для понимания.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дополнительными параметрами являются аргументы для функции

```
setTimeout(f, 1000, 10, 'string', false);

function f(integer, string, bool) {
    console.log(integer, string, bool);
}
```

[image: log]

---

Не только значения могут находиться в аргументе

```
setTimeout(f, 1000, 'курочка', function(doing) {
    console.log(doing);
});

function f(chicken, todo) {
    todo(chicken + ' снесла яйко');
}
```

[image: chicken]

Comment: то есть во втором примере в саму функцию, которая будет выполнятся в таймаут, передается параметр и функция, в которой в свою очередь передается еще один параметр, и потом мы можем этим пользоваться в теле функции таймаут, я правильно понял?

Comment: @ArtemPalamarchuk, всё так. Это называется `callback`

Comment: функция, которая передается как аргумент в другую функцию? я просто пытаюсь все очень хорошо понять, потому расспрашиваю

Comment: @ArtemPalamarchuk, это функция обратного вызова. Исполняемый код передаётся аргументом. [Туц](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CgV80.png). Теоретически передаваемая функция работает в теле `f`, а не `setTimeout`